# Monitor location of my phone

Tags: android, node.js, api, geolocation

I would like to make my own smart thermostat (A raspberry pi running a nodejs server with access to the thermostat via REST API calls) with the following main features:

- When noone is at home, lower the set temperature
- when someone is getting home (the distance to the house is decreasing), increase the set temperature

But in order to do this I need to know the location of the registered persons. I was hoping to retrieve the locations by using Google's location sharing (via a REST API). But apperently that is not possible. Which other solutions are availble?

My idea was to install an app on my phone that registers the location of the phone which can be accessed via a REST API. But I dont know if such an app exists?

Answer (score 0):

You could make your own Android app which monitors your location every X minutes and sends this data through to the server. You could also make the app a bit smarter by having the server tell it what locations to monitor and if the current location is either inside or outside those locations (different from the previously recorded location) to only then have it send a message to the server.